# catboost does not overfit - how is that possible?

Tags: overfitting, boosting, catboost

I'm fitting and evaluating a `CatBoostRegressor` and a `XGBRegressor` to the same regression problem. I tried matching their hyperparameters as closely as possible, yet I'm seeing something strange: catboost test error is monotonically decreasing! Why is that? NOTE that I switched off the fancy `boosting_type` and it's `plain`.

catboost learning curve:
[image: catboost]

xgboost learning curve:
[image: xgboost]

catboost get_all_params:

```
{'nan_mode': 'Min',
 'eval_metric': 'RMSE',
 'iterations': 1000,
 'sampling_frequency': 'PerTree',
 'fold_permutation_block': 0,
 'leaf_estimation_method': 'Newton',
 'boosting_type': 'Plain',
 'feature_border_type': 'GreedyLogSum',
 'bayesian_matrix_reg': 0.1000000015,
 'l2_leaf_reg': 3,
 'random_strength': 1,
 'rsm': 1,
 'boost_from_average': True,
 'model_size_reg': 0.5,
 'approx_on_full_history': False,
 'subsample': 0.8000000119,
 'use_best_model': True,
 'random_seed': 0,
 'depth': 6,
 'has_time': False,
 'fold_len_multiplier': 2,
 'border_count': 254,
 'classes_count': 0,
 'sparse_features_conflict_fraction': 0,
 'leaf_estimation_backtracking': 'AnyImprovement',
 'best_model_min_trees': 1,
 'model_shrink_rate': 0,
 'loss_function': 'RMSE',
 'learning_rate': 0.009999999776,
 'score_function': 'Cosine',
 'task_type': 'CPU',
 'leaf_estimation_iterations': 1,
 'bootstrap_type': 'MVS',
 'permutation_count': 4}
```

xgboost get_params:

```
{'base_score': 0.5,
 'booster': 'gbtree',
 'colsample_bylevel': 1,
 'colsample_bynode': 1,
 'colsample_bytree': 1,
 'gamma': 0,
 'importance_type': 'gain',
 'learning_rate': 0.01,
 'max_delta_step': 0,
 'max_depth': 6,
 'min_child_weight': 1,
 'missing': None,
 'n_estimators': 1000,
 'n_jobs': 1,
 'nthread': None,
 'objective': 'reg:linear',
 'random_state': 0,
 'reg_alpha': 0,
 'reg_lambda': 1,
 'scale_pos_weight': 1,
 'seed': None,
 'silent': False,
 'subsample': 1,
 'verbosity': 1}
```

Comment: In addition to the general principles outlined in the answer from @usεr11852 it seems that `catboost` is still learning (very slowly) at 700 trees. The minimum test MSE is about 1.2 for `xgboost` while the last test MSE for `catbost` seems to be about 1.4; see if going out to a few thousand trees finds a minimum closer to 1.2 for `catboost`.

Comment: @EdM (+1) Yeah, obviously, I wanted to make that point too but forgot! `xgboost`  achieves a substantially better minima way sooner.

Answer (score 3):

As it stands the two runs are not directly comparable. For example, off the bat, we can see that:

1. `catboost` uses a stronger $L_2$ regularisation on the weights ($3$ instead of $1$ in `xgboost`).
2. `catboost` uses different bagging/subsampling in terms of rows ($0.8$ instead of $1.0$ in `xgboost`).
3. `catboost` uses a different way than `xgboost` to built its trees; symmetric instead of best-first in XGBoost.
4. `catboost` uses an extra regularisation parameter (`bayesian_matrix_reg`) to regularise leaf values calculation (the non-diagonal ones when computing the hessian on the leafs); strictly speaking `xgboost` do not have the same functionality.

Please note that the above points are not even a very in-depth look. While we might expect the same qualitative behaviour between different implementations of a general computational framework (e.g. lowering the depth of the base-learner trees decreases the chance of over-fitting), the effect size might not be comparable. As these implementations incorporate a number of computational techniques to accelerate and/or make them more stable, the direct comparison of their behaviour is unreliable.